# Can I restore an iPhone from iPod Touch Backup?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, backup

If I buy an iPhone, can I restore it (along with app data) from an iPod Touch backup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems feasible. The last post on [this site](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=527801) says someone got it to work. [Do an actual backup](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1414) (not just sync) though.

Comment: Thomas is correct, you must backup, not simply sync as I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, when you first sync your iphone, you will be prompted to do so, so yes!

I'd recommend you to do a sync on your ipod before syncing the iphone.

Answer (score 1):

This does not work, just tried with new iPhone 5 and the settings were that of the iPod i.e. no app for messages, calls or any other iPhone standards :s

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is possible using iCloud. As long as you have your iPod backed up to iCloud, then, it will appear under the list of iCloud backup(s) available to restore from.

When you start your iPhone, and are prompted with the option of where to restore from, choose iCloud. The backup of your iPod touch will appear.  Select that to restore.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to restore the iPhone from your iPod Touch's backup. Backup the iPod touch, then restore from that backup in iTunes. You should be able to select the backup from the list that pops up. Although the iPhone will be restored from the iPod Touch's backup, iTunes should recognize it as a separate device.

Answer (score 0):

When I got my first iPhone three years ago (iPhone 4), this worked partially. Obviously, it worked fine. But every now and then the iPhone was not able to receive phone calls any more. The caller did not recognize it because he got the dialing tone, not the busy tone.

I could only solve that problem by resetting the iPhone and not restoring the old iPod backup.